# How do i get all lines of my MatLab (.m) files to run?

Tags: matlab

I have a .m file, that when i run it manually (meaning already in MatLab, and then type the three lines) it runs just like it should.

What im trying to do is put those three lines into a m file and have it run instead of me having to type the lines once im in MatLab

This is the m file im trying to run its called "ABOVE2019_TF01_MatLabCommands_Test.m"

These are the three lines in it:

```
in_dir_list = {'/j078_8/58667_TF01_G11','/j078_8/58667_TF01_G09',};
out_dir_list = {'/j078_8/58667_TF01_G11','/j078_8/58667_TF01_G09',};
resid_process_GPS(in_dir_list,out_dir_list);
```

(again running those three lines within MatLab works exactly like I would expect)

So i try to run the ABOVE2019_TF01_MatLabCommands_Test.m file like this

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2017a.app/bin/matlab -r "cd /volumes/promiseraid9/workspace/colleen/NewResiduals/j078_8; try, run('ABOVE2019_TF01_MatLabCommands_Test.m'); end; quit"
```

It doesn't error or anything it just exits out of MatLab instead of running the third line

If instead i changed the third line of the m file to just print out what in_dir_list it.  The above command will print that out no problem.  But the problem comes with the third line.  For whatever reason the above code will not run the third line.  What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is `resid_process_GPS`?

Comment: And how do you know that this command is not completing? What is it you are not observing which you expect to?

Comment: I am pretty sure something is wrong with your relative path. You are changing to a directory `j078_8` and you then use the same in your script. This would imply your path are `/volumes/promiseraid9/workspace/colleen/NewResiduals/j078_8/j078_8/58667_TF01_G11` with the j078_8 duplicated.

Comment: i was cutting down the path name for space on here.  This is the full path that i use /volumes/promiseraid9/workspace/colleen/NewResiduals/j078_8/58667_TF01_G11

Comment: resid_process_GPS is a script that another co-worker wrote, it uses the in_dir_list, and the out_dir_list as inputs for the script

Comment: I know the command is not completing because then there would be an output on the screen it wouldn't just go back to ">>" if it were working correctly there would be an output with a solution shown to the user.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `try` statement without catching or handling any exceptions that occur. Due to this, any errors which occur inside your script ABOVE2019_TF01_MatLabCommands_Test.m would not be returned to the command line.

You can verify this by running the following code from the command line:

`try; asdfasdfalwelknwerewr_THIS_LINE_SHOULD_ERROR; end;`

You should use a `catch` statement to handle any exceptions returned.

If you are running this from outside of the MATLAB desktop environment (which maintains a path to which to search for functions), are you sure that your functions are located within the search path? As in, is `resid_process_GPS` located within the folder named `/j078_8`?

Comment: ahh thank you, when i cd'd back to where it should be i now have it working, so i just added that extra cd and then that third line, and it worked